# The radius of convergence of the hypergeometric function $_2F_1$ (Ahlfors)

Tags: complex-analysis, hypergeometric-function

In Ahlfors' complex analysis text, page 317 he discusses the radius of convergence of the hypergeometric function $_2F_1(a,b;c;z)$ (which he denotes by $F(a,b,c,z)$):

> The radius of convergence of the hypergeometric series can easily be found by computation, but it is more instructive to use pure reasoning. In the first place, we know that $F(a,b,c,z)$ can be continued analytically along any path which does not pass through the point $1$ and does not return to the origin. Hence a single-valued branch of $F(a,b,c,z)$ can be defined in the unit disk $|z| < 1$ (because the disk is simply connected), and it follows that the radius of convergence is at least equal to one.

I have several questions regarding his discussion:

1. How do "we know that $F(a,b,c,d)$ can continued analytically along any path..."?
2. In order to establish a single valued analytic branch in the unit disk, it appears the author applies the monodromy theorem. However, this theorem requires the existence of analytic continuation along *any* arc; this makes the exception of "[the arc] does not return to the origin" a problem. How can the monodromy theorem work this way?

Thanks!

Comment: 1. follows from Cauchy's theorem.

Comment: @RonGordon How can you apply Cauchy's theorem without knowing  where the function is analytic in advance?